# Naruto Shippuden episodes after The final battle

Tags: naruto

After watching the final battle between Naruto and Sasuke and the `Naruto Uzumaki` episode, I stopped watching the series because I thought it was over. Now i see there are about ~15 more episodes.

Are the episodes after the `479 - Naruto Uzumaki` (480-500) canon? Or are these episodes some fillers after the actual plot?

Comment: The question asks specifically for episodes 480+ which are not mentioned in the old answered. Maybe that one should be updated then.

Comment: @Proxy there's an answer linking the filler site you mentioned, I agree the answer could and should be updated though.

Comment: ah i did not check the links, just the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, they are filler (well at least compared to the manga version) because the manga ends after their fight and we only got one more chapter in the future when both Naruto and Sasuke have become parents. (also we got a quick look at other characters).

Some of the episodes (483+) do show some flashback for the characters that we did not know before but they were never shown in the manga before, so if you follow the manga they are still considered "filler". And there is also the weeding :P.

Anyway the situation on them is not 100% clear, i guess it depends how you define filler for yourself.

Here is a list that can help you for a bit.

https://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto-shippuden